# How to create nested elements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, nested, element

Here's my HTML. I target to create elements in Javascript and insert it into div with the class "wrap" but didn't succeed.

```
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="shelf">
   <div class="shelf-background">
     <div class="base">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>


   var base = document.createElement('div');
   var shelfBackground = document.createElement('div');
   var wrap = document.querySelector(".wrap");
   var shelf = document.createElement('div');
   shelfBackground.className = "shelf-background";
   base.className = "base";
   shelf.className = "shelf";

   shelfBackground.appendChild(base);
   wrap.append(shelf, shelfBackground, shelfBackground.appendChild(base));
```

I get

```
   <div class="wrap">
     <div class="shelf"></div>
        <div class="shelf-background"></div>
     <div class="base"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: To clarify - you are attempting to create the example structure up top (wrap > shelf > shelf-background > base) but are getting the flat structure at the bottom? I'd recommend reading how [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) and [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) actually work.

Comment: @smashed-potatoes  Yes, this is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you are appending base to the background, and then appending all of the elements to the `wrap` element at the top level. Also note, when you call `shelfBackground.appendChild(base)`, it returns the appended child `base` which is why it is the last element in your output structure.

What you need to do is instead append the elements based to their respective parents, i.e.:

```
...
// Build the structure from the bottom up
shelfBackground.appendChild(base);  // shelf-background > base
shelf.appendChild(shelfBackground); // shelf > shelf-background > base
wrap.appendChild(shelf);            // wrap > shelf > shelf-background > base
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var wrap = document.querySelector(".wrap");

var base = document.createElement('div');
var shelfBackground = document.createElement('div');
var shelf = document.createElement('div');

base.className = "base";
shelfBackground.className = "shelf-background";
shelf.className = "shelf";

shelfBackground.appendChild(base);
shelf.appendChild(shelfBackground);
wrap.appendChild(shelf);
document.appendChild(wrap);
```